# Does the following proof about quadratic fields work for negative $d$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I understand the proof if it only works for positive  deltas if $d$ can be negative, I don’t know why it works. I don’t think it works though. Please tell me[image]

Comment: The proof seems to work fine regardless of the sign of $d$. The conclusion itself is certainly true for negative $d$ as well as positive.

Comment: Why do you think $d$ would need to be positive?

Comment: If $d$ is negative, $b^2 d$ is not in $Z + \frac{1}{4}$ because say $d=-3$ then we get ($-3y^2-3y+ \frac{-3}{4}$) for $b^2d$

Comment: I assumed since $b$ is a half integer, it can be written as $y+\frac{1}{2}$ (my problem is with case $2$ not case $1$

Comment: $-3y^3-3y-\frac{3}{4}=-3y^3-3y-1+\frac{1}{4}$

Comment: Wow, that’s the most beautiful thing I have seen this week. Please make a answer so I can give you best answer. Thank you